# Файлы конфигурации для сайта с двойным доменом

Tags: apache, httpd, php

Попытаюсь объяснить  как понимаю :D

Имеем:Есть сервер на `redhat 5`, на нем крутится сайт `php+Apache`, на сервере есть еще `Parallels Plesk Panel`, у сайта 2 домена которые ведут на одну и туже стартовую страницу, но потом разводят на разные под домены по типу `forum.site.com` (en) и `forum.site.ru` (ru).Есть файл который конфигурит доступ к сайту с двух доменов, но разводит потом при переходе на форумы. Если запустить панель плеска, файл затрется. Того кто писал это дело нет и не найти.

Что нужно:Предположения где может быть этот файл ?

ЗЫСервер с ограниченными возможностями - `locate` не работает. Файла `.htaccess` в `/var/www/` нету.`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` - вполне стандартный.

Comment: а разница в чем ? может просто в плеске второй домен завести ? ну и ещё /var/www/vhosts/site.com/vhost.conf не перетирается plesk'ом

Comment: Я боюсь что линковка на под домены поломается, я ошибаюсь? Можно смело заводить в плеске второй домен и это не повлечет последствия?

Comment: я не очень понял вашу задачу.

Comment: Есть еще find... А не работает - это как? Возможно,     sudo updatedbпоможет?

Comment: А что есть в     /etc/apache2/sites-available и     /etc/apache2/sites-enabled?

Comment: 1) > я не очень понял вашу задачу.нужно было найти место положение неизвестного файла2)> не работает - это как? Возможнокак то так :D> command not foundsudo доступа не былоPSОбъявился предыдущий админ, все нашлось :    /var/www/vhosts/site.ru/conf/httpd.include